# UWP DeviceWatcher skips from Created to EnumerationComplete

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, win-universal-app

I've written a UWP class library that doesn't seem to scan for BLE devices. Looking at the DeviceWatcher, it skips from the status Created to EnumerationComplete. I've tried creating a manifest for my library but the issue persists. Below is some of the code, and my manifest.

Adapter.cs

```
private DeviceWatcher deviceWatcher;

public override IList<IDevice> ConnectedDevices => ConnectedDeviceRegistry.Values.ToList();

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to store all connected devices
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<string, IDevice> ConnectedDeviceRegistry { get; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Registry used to store device instances for pending operations : connect 
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<string, IDevice> DeviceOperationRegistry { get; }

    public Adapter(DeviceWatcher deviceWatcher)
    {
        Platform = PLATFORM.WINDOWS;
        DeviceOperationRegistry = new Dictionary<string, IDevice>();
        ConnectedDeviceRegistry = new Dictionary<string, IDevice>();

        this.deviceWatcher = deviceWatcher;
        /*DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(
            aqsAllBluetoothLEDevices,
            requestedProperties,
            DeviceInformationKind.AssociationEndpoint);*/

        deviceWatcher.Added += DeviceWatcher_Added;
        deviceWatcher.Updated += DeviceWatcher_Updated;
        deviceWatcher.Removed += DeviceWatcher_Removed;
        deviceWatcher.EnumerationCompleted += DeviceWatcher_EnumerationCompleted;
        deviceWatcher.Stopped += DeviceWatcher_Stopped;
    }

    protected override Task StartScanningForDevicesNativeAsync(Guid[] serviceUuids, bool allowDuplicatesKey, CancellationToken scanCancellationToken)
    {

        // clear out the list
        DiscoveredDevices.Clear();

        deviceWatcher.Start();

        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
```

BleImplementation.cs

```
string[] requestedProperties = { "System.Devices.Aep.DeviceAddress", "System.Devices.Aep.IsConnected", "System.Devices.Aep.Bluetooth.Le.IsConnectable" };

    // BT_Code: Example showing paired and non-paired in a single query.
    string aqsAllBluetoothLEDevices = "(System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:=\"{bb7bb05e-5972-42b5-94fc-76eaa7084d49}\")";

    DeviceWatcher deviceWatcher;

    protected override IAdapter CreateNativeAdapter()
    {
        deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(
                aqsAllBluetoothLEDevices,
                requestedProperties,
                DeviceInformationKind.AssociationEndpoint);
        return new Adapter(deviceWatcher);
    }
```

Package.appxmanifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest">
  <Prerequisites>
    <OSMinVersion></OSMinVersion>
    <OSMaxVersionTested></OSMaxVersionTested>
  </Prerequisites>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="" StartPage="">
      <VisualElements DisplayName="" Description=""
           Logo="" SmallLogo=""
           ForegroundText="" BackgroundColor="">
        <SplashScreen Image="" />
      </VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>

  <Identity Name="MyCompany.MySuite.MyApp"
            Version="1.0.0.0"
            Publisher="CN=MyCompany, O=MyCompany, L=MyCity, S=MyState, C=MyCountry"/>

  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>MyApp</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>MyCompany</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>images\icon.png</Logo>
  </Properties>

  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <!--BT_Code: Always declare the bluetooth capability when using Bluetooth-->
    <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Comment: Is this a UWP class library? where is the .appxmanifest file? It seems that UWP class library doesn't need a .appxmanifest file. Could you provide a minimum project for your issue?